# My code does not delete from the XML file and I cannot seem to find out what's wrong

Tags: java, performance, swing

This is what the code looks like when ran

[image: 1]

Im trying to make my code delete the selected username from the combobox. It only deletes it from the combobox and not the XML File. Any insight on why it doesnt delete from the XML file?

Here is the code snippet:

```
public DeleteUserFrame() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        String path = "res/credentials.xml";
        File f = new File(path);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder build = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = build.parse(f);

        /* Combobox contents */
        try {
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Element nNode = (Element) nList.item(temp);
                String username = nNode.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0).getTextContent();
                String isAdmin = nNode.getElementsByTagName("isAdmin").item(0).getTextContent();
                if (isAdmin.equals("false")) {
                    userList.addItem(username);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Button Events */
        deleteUserButton.addActionListener(delete -> {
            String deleteUser = (String) userList.getSelectedItem();
            try {
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++){
                    Node currentNode = nList.item(temp);
                    String userName = currentNode.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                    if (userName.equalsIgnoreCase(deleteUser)){
                        Node user = currentNode.getParentNode();
                        NodeList siblings = user.getChildNodes();
                        for (int i = 0; i < siblings.getLength(); i++) {
                            Node sibling = siblings.item(i);
                            if (sibling.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                user.removeChild(sibling);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                userList.removeItem(deleteUser);
                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                transformer.transform(source, result);

                System.out.println("User (" + deleteUser + ") deleted!");

            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you run the delete code independent of the GUI? Ie a simple program that loads the XML deletes the element then writes the XML file again? Where are you saving the XML after deleting the element?

Comment: Try using a different library to [delete from the xml file](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-remove-an-element-from-xml-document/).